# r��duit xxx file does not exist

Tags: filesystem, special-characters

If I got files via mail or download files with  french characters on my Kubuntu 18.04   and I want to copy or delete or rename this files I got an error:

*The file or folder /home/rolf/ArtForLand/(r��duit)IMG_xxx  does not exist.*
what ever file type, like pdf or jpg. And it definitely exist, I just can't do anything with it.

The characters are replaced with a rhombic and a question mark inside.

It is always with french characters (maybe with others too)

This problem does't prevail on Ubuntu 18.04.5

My Kernelversion is : 5.4.0-62-generic, on the Ubuntu 18.04.5  I don't know.

Comment: Have you tried to rename it using terminal? Something like `mv /home/rolf/ArtForLand/\(r*IMG_xxx*.jpg ~/good-name.jpg` .

Comment: Not yet, thanks. I can't use that PC now, will try as soon as possible.